MFC Application exit code always 20
Taking a default MFC based single dialog appplication, I'm trying to prevent the default behaviour where the Escape or Enter key will cause the dialog to close.
However whilst I'm able to acheive this, I've discovered that the application exit code is now always returns 20, regardless of the value I pass to EndDialog.
In the below test I've prevented the Escape key:
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication10Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCANCEL, &CMFCApplication10Dlg::OnBnClickedCancel) // Triggers when Escape key pressed
    ON_WM_CLOSE() // Added WM_CLOSE to handle the close
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

OnBnClickedCancel occurs when pressing Escape, so to prevent the application closing I do not call OnCancel
void CMFCApplication10Dlg::OnBnClickedCancel()
{
    //CDialogEx::OnCancel(); // Not calling OnCancel
}

I've added the OnClose to allow the dialog to still be closed using the top right Close button
void CMFCApplication10Dlg::OnClose()
{
    CDialogEx::EndDialog(0); // Call the EndDialog with 0
}

How can I disable the escape key and also return an exit code of 0
Expecting: An exit code of 0
Actual: Getting an exit code of 20

Why is there a button with ID IDCANCEL in your dialog if you do not wish the dialog manager to close the dialog when [Esc] is pressed? Just remove it and you won't have to fight the dialog manager.

Becuase if I remove the Cancel button completely, the default behaviour of the [Esc] key is still triggering the dialog to close, which is what I'm trying to prevent

@user20716902 per Dialog Box Keyboard Interface, try handling WM_COMMAND and discard the message when wParam=IDCANCEL

@RemyLebeau Thank you yes I can discard IDCANCEL to prevent the dialog closing with [Esc] But this doesn't solve my main problem, when closing with the dialogs X close button. My app is exiting with exit code 20, how can I change this behaviour. I would like the exit code to be 0

@user20716902 Instead of handling WM_COMMAND, you can also just override CDialog::OnCancel(). But in any case, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. EndDialog() has nothing to do with the process exit code, the value you pass to EndDialog() is simply passed back to the caller who is displaying the dialog modally. Nothing more. So your exit code of 20 has to be coming from somewhere else that we can't see.

This one is odd. EndDialog() properly returns the argument as DoModal() returns into user code (InitInstance()). Returning from there, however, the code winds up in MFC's AfxWinMain() implementation that does some weird cleanup and ultimately overwrites the return code with the return value from the application singleton's CWinApp::ExitInstance(). During that, it attempts to handle (trailing) messages (WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, specifically) and returns its wParam.

@IInspectable That would imply that that the exit code is being set to HTCLOSE. Which kind of makes sense since the dialog is being closed. But it makes no sense that 1) WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN would be processed when WinMain() is cleaning up after the dialog is closed, and 2) why would anyone set the exit code to the wParam of WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN to begin with?

What are you trying to do exactly? For an application displaying a UI the launcher typically does NOT examine its exit code, as with command-line apps. And lacking the [OK] and [Cancel] buttons, the only way to close the app is from the system menu (or the X button on the title bar). So what would the exit-code return exactly?

@ConstantineGeorgiou, I am trying to set the exit code to 0 when the user clicks the top right system [X] button . AND prevent the default close behaviour when a user presses [ESC] key. For example when Notepad is closed by clicking [X] the return code IS 0.

@RemyLebeau Returning the wParam of the final message is standard practice. Unless you're doing something crazy that message will be WM_QUIT and its wParam carries the intended exit code (passed into PostQuitMessage()).

@IInspectable Yes, I'm aware of that. In a standard message loop, WM_QUIT is always the last message, since it is the only message that makes GetMessage() break the loop. In this case, it doesn't make sense to me that MFC would handle WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN and copy its wParam to WM_QUIT to be returned as the exit code. I'm not debating you are seeing that happen. I'm just saying that seems a stupid thing for it to do.

@user20716902 if you want to force the exit code to 0, then why don't you simply update your program's WinMain() to return 0 instead of returning what AfxWinMain() returns?

@RemyLebeau MFC doesn't allow you to customize its _tWinMain implementation. What does work, however, is replacing the EndDialog() call with a call to PostQuitMessage(), but I do not understand the consequences. Another option is to take things into your own hands and just ExitProcess() after the dialog has been dismissed.

When you create an MFC "Dialog Application" you usually want to disable the Enter and Esc key processing, as this is the main application window, while still being able to close the application from the system menu or the close button on the titlebar.
For the [Enter] key you can override the dialog's OnOK() member (the default implementation closes the dialog):
void CMyDlg::OnOK()
{
    // CDialogEx::OnOK(); Don't Close
}

For the [Esc] key there are various techniques. One is override the OnCancel() member:
void CMyDlg::OnCancel()
{
    // Disable Closing on Esc press
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000) == 0)
        CDialogEx::OnCancel(); // Close only if NOT caused by [Esc]
}

Or override OnCancel() and add a few lines to the Wizard-generated OnSysCommand() member too:
void CMyDlg::OnCancel()
{
    //CDialogEx::OnCancel(); Don't Close
}

void CMyDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else if (nID == SC_CLOSE) // Add these 2 lines
        CDialogEx::OnCancel();
    else CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
}

Other developers override the PreTranslateMessage() member.
As for the exit-code, I think it makes no sense at all, as I noted in the comments. The application will be returning 0 if you click the [X] button, but what else should it be returning? And under what conditions?
Anyway, CWinApp derives from CWinThread, you can try overriding Run(), and in the implementation call the parent-class Run() (CWinApp::Run() or CWinAppEx::Run()), discard its return value and return always 0. The wizard-generated override of InitInstance() returns FALSE for a dialog app, which means initialization failure, and may be this is why you are getting a non-zero exit-code.
A side-note, if your project is new and all you wanted is an MFC application displaying a "Main Form", like in VB or C#, you can try using not a "Dialog Application" template, but instead an SDI application without document/view support (uncheck the option). It still contains a view object though. The view-type can be CFormView, which is a dialog-resource-based view, and the application behaves better, avoids problems like those in your app, supports features like the ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI handlers and keyboard accelerators, and offers goodies like toolbars, status-bar and dockable panes, all generated by the Wizard. That is, it's a proper application, not a dialog-box repurposed as an application window.

EDIT:
Checked it in a test-application, and found that the Run() override trick doesn't work, because Run() isn't called if InitInstance() returns FALSE, which is the case for a Wizard-generated "MFC Dialog Application". However, you can override ExitInstance(), which is always called before termination:
int CMyApp::ExitInstance()
{
    CWinAppEx::ExitInstance(); // Discard the return value
    return 0;
}

The return value was 2 btw (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND), not 20. It seems MFC returns this pseudo-error if InitInstance() returns FALSE.

Thanks for the detailed answer. When I was using the method detailed in my question using OnClose and EndDialog(0), I was definetely getting a return value of 20, but your approach of checking key state in OnCancel, does fix that behaviour and I then get a return value of 2.

Overriding ExitInstance solved the problem. As MS states "0 indicates no errors, and values greater than 0 indicate an error" Which is why I raised the question in the first place as I was surprised to see my app retuning exit codes other than 0, when I knew no errors had occured.
